# Gradle: applicationVariants.all skips one variant

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Gradle to compile my Android project:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release 
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            def file = variant.outputFile
            def fileName = file.name
            fileName = fileName.replace(".apk", "-renamed.apk")
            variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
        }
    }
}
```

Not all output files are renamed, it always skips 1 file. Why?

```
myapp-debug-unaligned-renamed.apk    <-renamed, OK!
myapp-release.apk                    <-NOT renamed, WRONG!
myapp-release-unaligned-renamed.apk  <-renamed, OK!
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved using this code:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release 
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def apk = variant.packageApplication.outputFile;
        def newName = apk.name.replace(".apk", "-renamed.apk");
        variant.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);
        if (variant.zipAlign) {
            variant.zipAlign.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName.replace("-unaligned", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

The block `applicationVariants.all {...}` is now outside the `release {...}` block.

I think `variant.zipAlign.outputFile` makes the difference.

Comment: The syntax has changed with the 1.0.0 version of the gradle plugin. See updated solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693309/renaming-apk-in-gradle/27369185#27369185

Answer (score 4):

There should be 3 output APK files when using your build.gradle configuration: debug unsigned unaligned, release signed aligned and release signed unaligned. There are two variables for `applicationVariant` to deal with output files: **outputFile** and **packageApplication.outputFile**, the former is used for zipalign and the later is used in general case.

So the proper way to rename all the files will be like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.zipAlign) {
        def oldFile = variant.outputFile;
        def newFile = oldFile.name.replace(".apk", "-renamed.apk")
        variant.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile)
    }

    def oldFile = variant.packageApplication.outputFile;
    def newFile = oldFile.name.replace(".apk", "-renamed.apk")
    variant.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I simplified it by removing one of your lines but essentially you need to change it like so:

```
android {

    buildTypes {
    ...
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def file = variant.outputFile
        def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-renamed".apk")
        variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }
}
```

Comment: bringing out the code from the buildTypes {} block does not solve the problem.

Comment: variants have outputFiles (plural) now.