# The .apk file does not exist on disk but it does

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Whenever I debug application, error appears that `... .apk file does not exist on a disk` and app doesn't launch.

After updating Android Studio, this error started happening.

I tried different solutions after a lot of searching. This includes:

1. Downgrading Android Studio (it starts giving plugins error and I don't want not to be able to use new Android Studio)
2. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk) solution with no luck.
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545579/emptythrowable-the-apk-file-apk-does-not-exist-on-disk) catering different problem but with possible solution of my problem. It didn't work too.
4. Referred to the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203395)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is very unclear where is is about. Please first tell what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that error I wrote. Android Studio is not debugging application, it always says the error i.e. `.apk file does not exist on disk`.

Comment: And why dont you tell at wich moment or action you get that error?

Comment: It's written at the first line, "whenever I debug the application". After building the gradle. When it's near to launch app on mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your path to your apk. Might there be some special characters in folder names. This also cause the adb to through this error.

Answer (score 6):

If you have something like this in your **build.gradle** file:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
         output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, baseFilename + defaultConfig.versionCode + "_" + defaultConfig.versionName + "_" + getDate() + ".apk")
    }
}
```

And this

```
def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('dd.MM.yyyy')
    return formattedDate
}
```

You should remove **getDate()** from output to fix your problem. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22460730/4255903) post also.