# renaming apk in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I wish to rename my apk from gradle. I have the following lines inside build

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->      
            def file = variant.outputFile
            def filename = file.name.replace("SomeXXX", "SomeYYY")
            variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, filename)

                    }
```

This successfully renames the apks but not the unaligned apks. Please someone throw some light on this.

Comment: Probably `applicationVariants` doesn't hold info about unaligned variants. But AFAIK it's quite easy to find unaligned variant when You know variant name.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787493/android-gradle-build-renaming-the-apk/16794456#16794456

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The gradle plugin has moved on since you posted this, however to get this working on with the current plugin (v1.0.0), you can use the following:-

```
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def alignedOutputFile = output.outputFile
        def unalignedOutputFile = output.packageApplication.outputFile

        // Customise APK filenames (to include build version)
        if (variant.buildType.zipAlignEnabled) {
            // normal APK
            output.outputFile = new File(alignedOutputFile.parent, alignedOutputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk"))
        }
        // 'unaligned' APK
        output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(unalignedOutputFile.parent, unalignedOutputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk"))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But where does the above snippet go? When I post it within android {...} in my build.gradle file I get a Cannot resolve symbol "variant" - running gradle 2.2.1 and Android Studio 1.0.2

Comment: @Zainodis that should go in the buildTypes section.

Comment: @karl thank you a lot for your comment! Meanwhile I realized that the gradle editor in Android studio is not quite finished yet, that's why the variant variable couldnt be resolved.

Comment: This doesn't work for me using gradle 2.12 from the command line. I put the snippet under buildTypes, and I get `Could not find property 'outputs' on BuildType_Decorated{name=variant...`