# Could not find property 'packageApplication' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@5635bcd2

Tags: android, gradle

Here is my build.gradle: https://github.com/SnowdreamFramework/android-gradle-template/blob/master/config/android.gradle

When i try to upgrade my project to use gradle 2.2.1 and  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1', 
then i compile and get errors as follows:

```
$ gradle wrappers --info --stacktrace
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file 'D:\workspace\snowdream\git\android-gradle-template\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'D:\workspace\snowdream\git\android-gradle-template\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'android-gradle-template', project ':app', project ':lib']
Evaluating root project 'android-gradle-template' using build file 'D:\workspace\snowdream\git\android-gradle-template\build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':app' using build file 'D:\workspace\snowdream\git\android-gradle-template\app\build.gradle'.
Compiling script 'D:\workspace\snowdream\git\android-gradle-template\config\android.gradle' using StatementExtractingScriptTransformer.
Compiling script 'D:\workspace\snowdream\git\android-gradle-template\config\android.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.
Evaluating project ':lib' using build file 'D:\workspace\snowdream\git\android-gradle-template\lib\build.gradle'.
Sonatype RELEASE BUILD
GITHUB RELEASE BUILD

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\workspace\snowdream\git\android-gradle-template\config\android.gradle' line: 68

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not find property 'packageApplication' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@5635bcd2.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:86)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'packageApplication' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@56
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.propertyMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:94)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at android_4nixinp4pz49dw91skfb0zyxg$_run_closure3.doCall(D:\workspace\snowdream\git\android-gradle-template\config\android.gradle:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:63)
        at org.gradle.listener.ActionBroadcast.execute(ActionBroadcast.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:165)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:160)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.addVariant(AppExtension.groovy:52)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantApiObjects(VariantManager.java:624)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createApiObjects(VariantManager.java:591)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:226)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$createAndroidTasks.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:462)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure9.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:407)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
        at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
        at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        ... 28 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 52.699 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

Comment: Please see my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693309/renaming-apk-in-gradle/27369185#27369185

Comment: Similar cause as [Could not find property 'processManifest'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302965/could-not-find-property-processmanifest-on-com-android-build-gradle-internal-a)

Answer (score 4):

We had to work around this same problem by changing our code to access `.packageApplication` this way:

```
 project.android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  variant = variant as ApplicationVariant // For type inference.
  variant.outputs.each { output ->
    output = output as ApkVariantOutput // For type inference.
    def packageTask = output.packageApplication
```

Comment: @JaySoyer try `applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      variant.outputs.each { output ->`

Answer (score 2):

according to this topic https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/ZhejVC54XXc/nlkTvBrvOcwJ,  my solution is :

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
def apk = variant.outputs[0].outputFile;
def newName = "";

newName = apk.name.replace(project.name, POM_NAME + "-v" + android.defaultConfig.versionName);
newName = newName.replace("-" + variant.buildType.name, "");
newName = newName.replace(".apk", "-" + variant.buildType.name.toLowerCase() + ".apk");

variant.outputs[0].outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);
if (variant.outputs[0].zipAlign) {
    variant.outputs[0].zipAlign.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName.replace("-unaligned", ""));
}
```

}